# PhpStorm Не видит импорта классов

Tags: php, ооп, phpstorm

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста. Начинаю путаться в своем коде, ибо писал его уже довольно давно. 
Дело в том, что в новый класс, я передаю ссылку на инициализированный класс. 
В общем, тут подсказка есть: https://yadi.sk/i/Syn-H9FfiVQWh
А если пытаться вызвать подсказку из класса, куда передается только $engine, то ее не будет.
Как сделать так, чтобы PHPStorm показывал подсказку во всех файлах? 
//UPD для ВОРОН

```
index.php:
require 'engine.class.php';
require 'template.class.php';
$engine = new engine();
$template = new template();
$template->setEngine($template);
$engine-> тут подсказка есть.
$template-> тут подсказка есть.

engine.php:
class engine{
    public function getSomeText(){
        return rand(1,9).'text';
    }    
}

template.php:
class template{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->engine = null;
    }
    public function setEngine($eng){
        $this->engine = $eng;
    }
    public function somefunc(){
        $this->engine-> тут подсказки нету, и быть не должно. Но я ее хочу тут.
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. вам нужна подсказка в `$game/$steam/$te` и так далее? Ну так надо показать сигнатуру их методов. Вообще это должно через phpdoc разруливаться, т.е. создаете документацию к методу где говориться какую переменную передаете и дальше у вас будут доступны методы указанного класса

Comment: Ненене. PhpStorm ничего не показывает, потому что не знает что они инициализированы в этом файле или из этого файла есть доступ к объекту.

Comment: В скрипте где инициализируются классы, он все показывает.

Comment: Либо я вас не понимаю, либо вы меня не понимаете. Можете привести минимальный код для воспроизведения? Вроде как достаточно будет всего двух файлов

Comment: Код тут не причем. Сейчас обьясню

Comment: В шапке написал.

Comment: 1) этот код не воспроизводит ошибку, т.к. нет остального 2) а пробовали нормально объявить `engine`? Т.е. добавить `protected $engine;` а к нему (т.е. перед ним) написать [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) `/** @var engine Should contain a description */`? Т.е. сделать то, о чем я и писал изначально. Это решает вашу проблему?

Comment: Мы можем воспользоваться скайпом? Я не могу точно сформулировать вопрос. Если да, то alexey_aristov . На аварке лампочка

Comment: Только что сделал phpdoc, проблему не решило.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ВВЕДЕНИЕ**

Создаем файлы с указанным вами содержимым. В методе `template::somefunc()`, действительно, на `$this->engine->` нет подсказки.

Смотрим на класс `template` и видим, что `engine` там не определен. Да, он где-то чем-то и как-то задается, но ведь задавать его могла не только строчка `$template->setEngine($template);` (у вас здесь опечатка, но она нам только на руку), но и строчка `$template->setEngine($engine);`

И что тогда должно отображаться в виде подсказки? Методы класса `template` или методы класса `engine`? А если таких строчек будет много и каждая передает свой объект? Или в `setEngine` будет передаваться что-то неопределенное? Например:

```
$class = $_REQUEST['class'];
$object = new $class;
$template->setEngine($object);
```

Что тогда должно отображаться в подсказках?

**ДОКУМЕНТИРОВАНИЕ КОДА**

Классы можно документировать. Классы надо документировать.

Это позволяет не только другим разобраться в вашем коде, но и вам быстро восполнить пробелы, если вы давно не работали с этим кодом.

Кроме того, при правильном [документировании](http://www.phpdoc.org/) различные IDE смогут выдавать вам различные подсказки по вашему коду (+ вы можете автоматически сгенерировать более-менее нормальную документацию по вашему коду).

Например, описав в вашем классе `template` атрибут `engine` мы можем указать класс, объект которого будет храниться в данном атрибуте (или какой-то интерфейс, реализуемый объектом). Т.е. исправив ваш класс следующим образом:

```
class template {

    /** @var engine Should contain a description */
    protected $engine;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->engine = null;
    }

    public function setEngine($eng){
        $this->engine = $eng;
    }

    public function somefunc(){
        $this->engine->getSomeText();
    }
}
```

в методе `somefunc` мы уже будем получать подсказки по доступным методам `engine`.

При этом даже если мы передадим туда объект класса `template` (как в вашем примере), IDE все равно будет показывать нам методы класса `engine`

Единственное, у меня че-то не получилось отобразить в подсказках описание метода и используемых переменных (возможно в PhpStorm это не предусмотрено), но тип возвращаемого значения (и тип переданных параметров) метода показан тот, что был указан в комментарии

**ПОСЛЕСЛОВИЕ**

Почему же тогда IDE нормально показывает методы в файле `index.php`? Ну так вы создаете объекты в том же файле, IDE Это видит, видит объект какого класса был создан и потому правильно указывает его доступные методы. Смотрите сами:

```
$engine = new template();
$engine-> // здесь будут методы класса template
$engine = new engine();
$engine-> // здесь будут методы класса engine
```

PS: проверял в PhpStrom 8.0.3

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ. Я не говорил ничего в сторону IDE, и понимаю почему в index.php отображается список методов и свойств. Цитата из топика 'тут подсказки нету, и быть не должно. Но я ее хочу тут'. Огромный и жирный + Вам, господин Ворон :).

Comment: @Алексей, т.е. phpdoc все-таки помог? В комментах к вопросу вы просто писали, что это не помогло. Если проблема осталась - скажите какую версию используете, буду на ней смотреть

Comment: /** @var engine */
Версия 8.0.3 Все работает, спасибо.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/FYOX0ZJqiWjgN